# write_xlsx results in error: "Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames" This despite data being a list of DFs

Tags: r, writexl

I need to write an excel file with multiple sheets named "Cases", "Coordinators", "Contacts"

I have checked the class of each--e.g., class(Cases)--and the result in each case is:

```
class(Cases)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I combine these dfs into a list called "compiledData" as follows:

```
compiledData <- c(Cases, Coordinators, Contacts)
```

and checked class of compiledData as follows:

```
class(compiledData)
[1] "list"
```

So, I am confused as to why the following code results in the following error:

```
write_xlsx(compiledData, "FileName.xlsx")
Error in write_xlsx(compiledData, "FileName.xlsx") : 
  Argument x must be a data frame or list of data frames
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I have been searching for two days for a solution, but have not found an answer. Apologies in advance if a solution has already been posted and I've not seen it.

One update: I changed `compiledData <- c(Cases, Coordinators, Contacts)` to:
`compiledData <- list(Cases, Coordinators, Contacts)` and the Excel file is now being created without error. My new problem is that the worksheets in the excel file are not labeled "Cases", "Coordinators", "Contacts"--they are Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store the data frames in a list (ie, `compiledData <- list(Cases, Coordinators, Contacts)`) the elements are unnamed. For instance, in this example:

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- tibble::tibble(A = 1:5, B = 1:5, C = 1:5)
comb <- list(df1, df2, df3)

names(comb)
# NULL
```

To export the to excel with the df names, you just have to name the elements in the list (ie, using `names()` or `setNames()`):

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- tibble::tibble(A = 1:5, B = 1:5, C = 1:5)
comb <- list(df1, df2, df3)

names(comb) <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
writexl::write_xlsx(comb, "test.xlsx")

# or one-liner

writexl::write_xlsx(setNames(comb, c("df1", "df2", "df3")), "test.xlsx")
```

Note: since you resolved your initial question (RE: properly exporting) but edited to pose a new one (RE: naming sheets), please edit your question to remove the original question and only focus on the new one. This will help future readers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I did away with the creation of "compiledData"

```
(compiledData <- c(Cases, Coordinators, Contacts)
```

And instead accomplished the writing of the excel file *with named worksheets* like this:
`write_xlsx(list(Cases = Cases, Coordinators = Coordinators, Contacts = Contacts), "test.xlsx"`)

It is a bit verbose and maybe a better way to do it, but it works :)

Comment: While this is a fine answer, it is essentially the same answer as that provided by @jpsmith.